# How to find the number of times a package has been installed for apt

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to generate metrics for packages I maintain to see how many times they've been installed from ros buildfarm deployment system through apt-get/other package managers. Is there a way to find this info from repositories.ros.org or any other links? Anyone I can contact to get these metrics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311518/how-to-find-the-number-of-times-a-package-has-been-installed-for-apt/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2018-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bit indirect and your package(s) may not be listed, but from [ROS Metrics Report extension](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-metrics-report-extension/4544) on ROS Discourse you can get to [awstats.osuosl.org/list/packages.ros.org](https://awstats.osuosl.org/list/packages.ros.org) which is the Awstats page for `packages.ros.org`.

From there to [this page for December, 2018](https://awstats.osuosl.org/reports/packages.ros.org/2018/12/awstats.packages.ros.org.html) and then finally to the [full list](https://awstats.osuosl.org/reports/packages.ros.org/2018/12/awstats.packages.ros.org.downloads.html) for the *Downloads (Top 10)* section.

`ctrl+f` on your package name should give you *some* statistics.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-12-27**:
Thanks for the answer, that's a really solid find thanks! However, my packages (and most packages) don't appear in that list, they look like mostly the core packages or things with very high install rates.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-28**:
Well, as I wrote:

> your package(s) may not be listed

It's all parsed data, so things below certain thresholds will not be shown.

Afaik this is as much detail as you're going to get, so if this doesn't cover it then I'm afraid the answer -- in your specific case -- is going to be ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-28**:
.. that you can't get those statistics (for now at least).